# Read and write Pandas DataFrame with multi-row and multi-column index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a multi-row and a multi-column index.

The row index names: (User_ID,User_Name). The column index names: (User_Type,Sample_ID).

The dataframe looks like this.

```
In: user_frame.head(2)

Out:

        Sample_Type TV  TV  Radio TV
        Sample_ID   1   2   3     4
User_ID User_Name
1000001 Jim         0.1 0.3 0.5   0.9
1000001 Julie       0.2 0.9 0.1   0.5
```

I want to write this to disk.

```
user_frame.to_csv(fi_path,{write_args})
```

And then read it back with the multi-row and a multi-column index in tact.

```
user_frame_new=pd.read_csv(fi_path,{read_args})
```

I have not found the correct write_args / read_args that keep both multi-row and multi-column index.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], [1, 2, 3]])
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["X", "Y"], ["aa", "bb"]])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(6, 4)), index=idx, columns=col)
df.index.names = "name1", "name2"
df.columns.names = "NAME1", "NAME2"

df.to_csv("tmp.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("tmp.csv", header=[0, 1], index_col=[0, 1])
```